# Given 2 strings, remove only one digit to make 1 string lexicographically smaller

Tags: java, string, lexicographic-ordering

I am trying to work through a coding problem of string manipulation in Java. The question is that

> Given two strings S and T consisting of digits and lowercase letters, you are allowed to remove only one digit from either string, count how many ways of removal to make S lexicographically smaller than T.

I came up with this test case myself. If s = '3ab' and t = 'cd', return 1. If s = '123ab' and t = '423cd', return 6.

My idea is to use 2 for loops and go through each string by checking if a char is digit, remove it and compare with the other string.

```java
private static int numSmaller(String s, String t){
    int ways = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++){
        StringBuilder sbs = new StringBuilder(s);
        if(Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))){
            sbs.deleteCharAt(i);
            String sub = sbs.toString();
            if(sub.compareTo(t) < 0) {
                ways++;
            }
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < t.length(); i++){
        StringBuilder sbt = new StringBuilder(t);
        if(Character.isDigit(t.charAt(i))){
            sbt.deleteCharAt(i);
            String sub = sbt.toString();
            if(s.compareTo(sub) < 0){
                ways++;
            }
        }
    }
    return ways;
}
```

As you can see the space complexity is pretty bad, and the code also seems redundant. Is there a way to optimize this piece of code? Does anyone see a way to not use a string builder or create a new string each time? Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Could you give a test case?

Comment: @oleg.cherednik Just did!

Comment: for `s = '123ab' and t = '423cd'` I have counted `9` different ways! `[123a:423cb], [123b:423cb], [12ab:423cb], [13ab:423cb], [23ab:423cb], [123ab:423c], [123ab:42cb], [123ab:43cb], [123ab:23cb]`

Comment: @oleg.cherednik So you are only allowed to remove numbers.

Comment: One way to improve your code is to not create your `StringBuilder` instances until you need them.  For example, if either `t` or `s` contain no digits, you never test them.  But you create a `StringBuilder` instance for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Move
_StringBuilder_ out of loops is the first thing your should do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it using `streams` and compared it to your approach with random strings of length 10.  I ran `1 million` test cases of those strings and the two methods provided the same results.

The stream part is fairly straightforward.  I use an `IntStream` to index into a string to build `substrings` based on digit location.  Then I filter based on a passed `BiFunction` lambda that acts as a two argument predicate.  Filtering on that I count the successes.

I do this twice, reversing the arguments and the predicate logic, and sum up the two counts.

```
long count = count(s1, t1, (a, b) -> a.compareTo(b) < 0);
count += count(t1, s1, (a, b) -> b.compareTo(a) < 0);   

public static long count(String s, String t, BiFunction<String, String, Boolean> comp) {

      return IntStream.range(0, s.length()).filter(
        i -> Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))).mapToObj(
              i -> s.substring(0, i) + s.substring(i + 1)).filter(
                    ss -> comp.apply(ss, t)).count();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In C# very easy you can do this code, below code will help you.

```
        private static int numSmaller(string s, string t)
    {
        int ways = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            StringBuilder sbs = new StringBuilder(s);
            if (Char.IsDigit(s[i]))
            {
                sbs.Remove(i,1);
                string sub = sbs.ToString();
                if (sub.CompareTo(t) < 0)
                {
                    ways++;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
        {
            StringBuilder sbt = new StringBuilder(t);
            if (Char.IsDigit(t[i]))
            {
                sbt.Remove(i,1);
                string sub = sbt.ToString();
                if (s.CompareTo(sub) < 0)
                {
                    ways++;
                }
            }
        }
        return ways;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the time complexity to O(m+n), where m, n are the length of S, T
I wrote C++ code and tested it works.

The idea is to compare the first character of S and T:

```
First count how many digits S and T have, then compare their first characters

if(S[0] < T[0])
    can remove any digits behind except for the first characters of S and T
    then check if you can remove S[0] or T[0] to make S<T
else
    check if you can remove S[0] or  T[0] to make S<T if can not, return 0;
```

Comment: It looks like this solution doesn’t work for s=“a1”, t=“a2”. There is additional complexity when there are equal letters. Have you handled this?

Answer (score 0):

```
System.out.println(getcnt(s1, t1) + getcnt(t1, s1));

    public static int getcnt(String a, String b) {
    int ways = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {

        if (Character.isDigit(a.charAt(i))) {

            String s = a.substring(0, i) + a.substring(i + 1);

            if (s.compareTo(b) < 0 || b.compareTo(s) < 0)
                ways++;

        }
    }
    return ways;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working solution with `O(n+m)` time complexity. Only the first character is important and based on the fact it's number of not we can decide how to deal with it.

```
public static int numSmaller(String s, String t) {
    return numSmaller(s,t,1);
}
public static int numSmaller(String s, String t,int n) {
    if(n==0){
        if(s.compareTo(t) < 0){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
    int output = 0;
    if(n==1){
        char sc = s.charAt(0);
        char tc = t.charAt(0);
        int sCount = digitCount(s);
        int tCount = digitCount(t);
        if(sc < tc){
            if(Character.isDigit(sc)){// s = '123ab' and t = 'c23cd',
                output += ((sCount-1)+tCount);//we need to delete exactly one character
                output+=numSmaller(s.substring(1),t,0);
            }else{
                output += (sCount)+tCount;
            }

        }else{
            if(!Character.isDigit(sc) && !Character.isDigit(tc) ){
                return 0;
            }
            if(Character.isDigit(sc)){
                output +=numSmaller(s.substring(1),t,0);
            }
            if(Character.isDigit(tc)){
                output +=numSmaller(s,t.substring(1),0);
            }
        }
    }
    return output;

}
 private static int digitCount(String s){
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
        char c = s.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isDigit(c)){
            count++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
 /**
    String s="a123ab";
    String t ="b423cd";
    System.out.println( numSmaller(s,t));
    
     * a23ab,b423cd
     * a13ab,b423cd
     * a12ab,b423cd
     * a123ab,b23cd
     * a123ab,b43cd
     * a123ab,b42cd
     *
     */
```

Comment: Fails with 
s: "ab12c"
t: "ab24z". Should be 3 but gives 0

Answer (score 0):

The O(n+m) solutions that relies on checking just the first characters, fail for this input

```
s = "ab12c"
t = "ab24z"
```

It is still a great improvement to check just the first characters, but that edge case must be handled

Answer (score 0):

This code works in Python, in case it's useful for you:

```
def solution(s, t):
    counter = 0
    len_s, len_t = len(s), len(t)
    
    for I in range(len_s):
        if s[I].isdigit():
            temp = s[:I] + s[I+1:]  # Remove the digit from s
            if temp < t:
                counter += 1
        elif len_s <= i : 
            break  # Break the loop if a non-digit character in s has a higher ASCII value than the corresponding character in t

    for I in range(len_t):
        if t[I].isdigit():
            temp = t[:I] + t[I+1:]  # Remove the digit from t
            if s < temp:
                counter += 1
        elif len_t <= i : 
            break  # Break the loop if a non-digit character in s has a higher ASCII value than the corresponding character in t

    return counter
```